# Opencart, Flat Charge for option (not related to Quantity)

Tags: opencart

I am having trouble with my order processing for Opencart 1.5.6. I have a series of checkboxes that if checked each cost $50.00. The problem is that the customer is ordering print materials in quantities of 500, 1000, 5000, etc. When they get to the shopping cart it charges the $50 extra for each option for each individual item ordered based on the quantity. This makes it so that their total skyrockets. If they pick one option for $50 and order 500 business cards they get charged an extra $25,000 for that one option.

The only solution that I can see is to have the Quantity be an option and only allow them to order one product but that does not allow them to change the Quantity of cards in the Cart.

**Is there anyway to set it up so that an option charges a flat rate not based on total quantity of the order?**

Comment: Well a workaround could be to sell products in packages of 500, 1000, 5000, etc. e.g.. one product would be "500 business cards". 

Or else make the quantity an option too, you could have radio buttons, "500", "1000", etc. so you could charge extra for the extra cards ordered, and just have one charge for the $50 option you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

When customizing OpenCart follow these steps.

1. Look to see if [this link](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension) has an extension that will do what you want.
2. If step 1 did not work. Go to your public_html file (the place that has all your code). Open the files that are related to your problem and edit those. There is also an OpenCart forum that will help with common problems.

As far as changing the settings on your payment function. Go look at `OpenCart->catalog->checkout` folder. Or maybe `OpenCart->admin->checkout`. You will need to find the function that adds quantity and gives value. You will need to change those around a little.